# React native: Display image in TestFlight not working

Tags: ios, image, react-native, testflight

I have app who I had uploaded to Testflight, Almost everything works fine, but there is one Image who not displays. This image is inside my IOS folder and displayed as a background Image in the package "RNSketchCanvas".

If run my App one the simulator it works perfect.

Here is the following code who I use to display the image:

```
localSourceImage={{
  filename:
   '/Users/username/Desktop/ProjectName/iOS/image.png',
    mode: 'AspectFit',
    directory: 'SketchCanvas.MAIN_BUNDLE',
 }}
```

Could it be the "PNG" format who is the problem or that I have to put the image inside "images.xcassets" or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the documentation states here:

https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas#background-image

you need to add the image to your native project. You should not even add it to an xcassets folder but just as a plain image file to your native App bundle. After that you can use it with the filename and directory to `RNSketchCanvas.MAIN_BUNDLE`. On Android you have to add it to resources.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The thing as that It works perfect on the simulator, and I have add then image under my native folder, but when upload it to AppStore/testflight it not works.

Comment: in simulator it works because the simulator can access your local files. You need to add it to your Xcode Project, not only to the folder. Only by adding it to your project like mentioned in the docu, Xcode will bundle it into your app and you can access it from the device. Read the documentation and do it step by step as described.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and I have used the below command to copy the assets to the IOS project

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

This solved the issue.

**And If your project is running on the old node version you need to make the below changes before building the project**

Go to 'Build Phrase' --> 'Bundle React Native code and images'

```
NODE_BINARY=Your local path for related node version
```

You can get the path from the below command

```
which node
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with React Native 0.63.3, where images loaded correctly locally but failed to load in the TestFlight IPA. Despite trying various solutions without success, I eventually identified that my assets weren't being bundled into the myapp.app.

Here's a simplified guide on how to resolve this:

1. Open your project in Xcode.
2. In the left sidebar, navigate to your project and select your app
   from the target section.
3. Go to "Build Phases."
4. Look for "Copy Bundle Resources" and click on it.
5. Use the '+' icon to add other items.
6. Navigate to your ios folder and select the 'assets' folder, then add
   it.

Additionally:
Ensure your images are present in the assets folder. If you can't find them, run the following command in your terminal to bundle again:

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

This addition ensures that your assets get bundled during the build process, resolving the issue of images not loading in TestFlight.